# Can you turn off the flashlight on the shotgun in Halo 5?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

We just started playing multiplayer in a custom game and we found out that we can't seem to turn off the flashlight on the shotgun. This could be a problem as it will give away our position. Can the light on the shotgun be turned off? If so, how?

Comment: I'm not sure so I'm just going to post a comment. I'm pretty sure there is no off option and that it provides light based on a sensor for low light areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot turn off the light on the shotgun. It is locked on by design as a balancing mechanic, it lets you know that Spartan is holding a shotgun and should not be engaged with in close range. There is a other weapons that use these light giveaway mechanics: Railguns while charging and Sniper weapons.